# If clause in Generic List

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, generic-list

I have some questions about GenericLists in PowerShell.
The script below prints all access rights on a file share for a specific user with his groups. Now I want to add a new row in my GenericList which shows from where (user/group) the right is inherited.

```cs
$User = "Testumgebung\cbruehwiler"
$UserOhneDomain = "cbruehwiler"
$Path = "T:\"
$List = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserOhneDomain

$GroupArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $GroupArrayList.Add($Group.Name) | Out-Null
}

# Fields we want in list, an array of calculated properties.
$OutputFields = @(
    @{name="Item" ;       expression={$_.Path.split(':',3)[-1]}}
    @{name="Rights" ;     expression={$Right.FileSystemRights}}
    @{name="AccessType" ; expression={$Right.AccessControlType}}
    @{name="From" ;       expression={$User}}
)
$FileSystemObjects = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}

foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User) {
            $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
        }
    }
}

foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        foreach ($GroupArrayItem in $GroupArrayList){
            if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq ("TESTUMGEBUNG\" + $GroupArrayItem)) {
                $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
            }
        }
    }
}

$List | Out-File C:\Users\cbruehwiler\Desktop\PermissionCheck.txt
```

The result looks like this:

```
Item                                       Rights  AccessType  From
----                                       ------  ----------  ----
T:\TestFolder                         FullControl       Allow  Testumgebung\cbruehwiler
T:\TestFolder                   Read, Synchronize       Allow  Testumgebung\cbruehwiler
T:\TestFolder  Write, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize       Allow  Testumgebung\cbruehwiler
```

The last row now prints only my user. However it should show the user or the group.

Comment: The fastest fix would be to set the `$User` string object to the value of `"Group: TESTUMGEBUNG\" + $GroupArrayItem` in the second loop, before you add the outputfields to the list.

Comment: Oh my god. Of course. Thanks. How could I miss this...

Answer (score 1):

You could even merge the two loops into one, like this:

```
foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        foreach ($GroupArrayItem in $GroupArrayList) {
            # not needed; just for convenience 
            [string]$id = $Right.IdentityReference

            # test if the $Right.IdentityReference corresponds with the user name
            if ($id -eq $User) {
                $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
            }
            # test if the $Right.IdentityReference without the 'Domain\' part can be found in the list of groups
            elseif (($id.Split("\", 2)[-1]) -in $GroupArrayList) {
                # set the $User variable to the value of $Right.IdentityReference
                $User = "Group: $id"
                $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
            }
        }
    }   
}
```